# Why is the variable 'index' not being returned and printed out like the variable 'mins'?

Tags: python-3.x

I do not know how to get an output that says the lowest number in the list AND the index of the lowest number

```
  '''
    def findMin(*args):
        mins = 0
        mins = min(args)
        index = args.index(mins)
        return mins
        return index
        
    
    minsResult = findMin(10, 5, -4, 2, 7, 8)
    print(minsResult)
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` is not returned because before that you're returning from function with `return mins`. To return both variables, use `return mins, index`. For example:

```
def findMin(*args):
    mins = min(args)
    index = args.index(mins)
    return mins, index
    

minsResult = findMin(10, 5, -4, 2, 7, 8)
print(minsResult)
```

Prints:

```
(-4, 2)
```